# Fill in value in column based on other column, power bi

Tags: powerbi

Hopefully this is a simple ask but I couldn't figure out how to find it on here.

I have data like this in Power Bi/Power Query:

[image]

There's repeated rows/instances for a few of the people in my data. But anytime there's a repeated row for that person, their name does not get repeated.  Luckily, I can tell its the same person because of the record_id column.

My simple question is:  Can I quickly have Power Bi fill in the blanks?  I.e. if record_id L1 is clearly "Erin" --- becauses thats what the first row of it was, can I have it fill in the rest of the missing L1 rows with "erin"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fill down operation in Power Query that looks like it will do what you want. Just be aware how your data is sorted before you fill. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column

Comment: Worked perfect.  Didn't work at first because the blanks needed to be converted to true nulls, but then it did.  I'll accept your answer once it lets me

Comment: Good stuff. Why won't it let you accept the answer out of interest?

Comment: It just wanted me to wait 10 mins from when I asked